# Do samsung Laser printers enfore toner expiry dates?

Tags: laser-printer

Background: I'm looking at a Samsung ML-1865 printer. I don't print that often.

Do Samsung toner cartridges have expiry dates?
If yes, does the printer refuse to use "expired" toner cartridges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some anecdotal evidence, I have had a Samsung ML-1665 printer for about a year, and I am still on the original toner.  I have never heard of printers expiring toner cartridges based on date.  I know that some printers refuse to print on "low" toner cartridges with varying degrees of what they consider low, but sometimes a good fix for that is to just remove the toner and shake it a bit, which resets whatever mechanism it has for determining fullness.

After some Googling, it seems that the only evidence I can come up with for expiration dates on printers is for a small set of [HP Inkjet Printers](http://www.hp.com/pageyield/en-019/articles/inkExpiration.html?cCode=us).  I couldn't find any evidence of this occurring on any laser printers, or any other inkjet printers produced by other vendors.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience I would say no.
The reason I say this is because I have 2 laser printers and I consistently refill their toner cartridge and reuse it. I don't do anything other than refill it and it seems to work fine. If there was some mechanism that marked the toners cartridge as expired then to the best of my knowledge and experience it's not there in my printers at least.

I bought the printers about 2 years ago and each was a recent model back then.

Answer (score 0):

I read that HP is starting to install date codes in lazer toner cartridges.   They will no longer work after date.